# Javascript: Subir multiples archivos en un solo envío con diferentes cajas input:file

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular5, fileupload

Cómo podría hacer con Javascript para generar un `input:file` múltiple pero tomando los archivos de diferentes input files, me explico:

```
<inpu type="file" name="file1">
<inpu type="file" name="file2">
<inpu type="file" name="file3">
```

Para enviarlos con Javascript usando ajax debería hacer algo como esto:

```
fd = new FormData();
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
fd.append('file1', file1, file1.name);
fd.append('file2', file2, file2.name);
fd.append('file3', file3, file3.name);
xhr.open('post', url, true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

Lo que yo necesito (porque mi aplicación crea diferentes campos `input:file` dinámicamente y no debo cambiar esa funcionalidad) es usar un código similar a esto:

```
fd.append('archivos', files, "archivos");
```

*Donde "files" es un arreglo de archivos.*

**¿Por qué debe ser así?**

Porque en Node estoy usando Multer y para subir archivos múltiples debo usar un middleware como el siguiente:

```
api.post('/equipos/uploadfiles', upload.array('archivos', 12), equipoController.uploadFiles);
```

**Dato:** Estoy usando Angular y la subida de archivos ya la tengo lista, pero uno por uno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución a mi problema fue realmente sencilla y la comparto con ustedes:

Todos los archivos los he añadido a aun arreglo y luego los iteré de la siguiente forma:

```
for(var i in files ) {
   fd.append('archivos', files[i], files[i].name );
}
```

Espero le sirva a alguien.

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras solución. HAHHA tardaste poco despues de pregutnar. Un saludo

Comment: No me lo vas a creer, pero antes de poner la publicación ya había pasado bastante tiempo (casi dos horas buscando) y rayos, poco despues era algo tan sencillo. Saludos!

Comment: Si, son cosas que pasan hehe. En 2 dias podrás marcar esta respuesta como aceptada. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias!!